# Pycharm wsl2 remote debugging: Remote file <remote_file_path> is mapped to the local path <local_file_path> and can't be found

Tags: pycharm, wsl-2

The module in the wsl2 PYTHONPATH cannot be found by remote debugger on pycharm when importing.
I made a debug line breakpoint at that import line and then step into the code and a file named `<frozen importlib._bootstrap>` opens up and informs me:

```
Remote file /mnt/c/Users/wilso/Desktop/Korem_lab/git/  is mapped to the local path C:\Users\wilso\Desktop\Korem_lab\git\  and can't be found. 
You can continue debugging, but without the source. 
To fix that you can do one of the following:
Edit settings of path mappingcin remote debug configuration
...
```

So i go to my path mapping configuration to make sure that the remote and local is linked correctly,
but the error doesn't go away.
Is this just a bug on the pycharm end? It's very frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I am afraid this is the case and it has been a longstanding bug. See [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-48387#focus=Comments-27-4849128.0-0) issue for example.

Answer (score 0):

To all people who has encounter same issue:

in my case , the issue is caused by error during module importing , for me ,the error is "no module name cv2" ,after i install the module by pip , the issue gone.

my advice : set breakpoint for every statement , step one by one to check which statement and which command cause a error

by the way in vscode , debugger also has similar  tab but with different text ,see pic 2
[image]

pic2:
[image]

ref:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-40745